# ui-router automatically redirects out of state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got the following route:

```
.state('app.base.patient', {
    url: '/store/:storeID/patient/:patientID',
    template: template,
    controller: patientCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        patientObj: ['$stateParams', 'patientResource', function($stateParams, patientResource) {
            if ($stateParams.patientID !== '') {
                return patientResource.get($stateParams.patientID);
            }

            return null;
        }]
    } 
});
```

I'm able to navigate to it through the app perfectly fine (using $state.go)
which gets me to (for example):

```
'/store/105/patient/8a7f7e785279bc1f015279be7cb40001'
```

But when I try to refresh the page on with the same url I get redirected to:

```
'/store/105/patient/'
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? I've been adding more and more logging but I can't see anything that looks obviously wrong

The "parent" view is the store select view:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.base.store', {
    url: '/store',
    template: template,
    controller: storeCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your state definition? Is app.base.patient nested in the app.base state? What does that state definition look like?

Comment: Sure, editing original question with details as comment is too small

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs indicate the states should be nested, but the state definitions do not reflect that. Your patient state should be nested in your store state. The patient state would change to something like this:

```
.state('app.base.store.patient', {
    url: '/patient/:patientID',
    template: template,
    controller: patientCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        patientObj: ['$stateParams', 'patientResource', function($stateParams, patientResource) {
            if ($stateParams.patientID !== '') {
                return patientResource.get($stateParams.patientID);
            }

            return null;
        }]
    } 
});
```

Meanwhile, your store state would look like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.base.store', {
    url: '/store/:storeID',
    template: template,
    controller: storeCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

Then, as long as your views are nested properly, you can navigate to the patient state from the store view like so:

```
ui-sref="app.base.store.patient({patientID: vm.patientID})"
```

Or in controller code like so:

```
$state.go("app.base.store.patient", { storeID: vm.storeID, patientID: vm.patientID });
```

Comment: ok, good catch but no go sadly.
I've updated the routes to work as follow:
app.base.store
app.base.patient

This is because the store view isn't a parent (the flow is select store -> select user, but the user selector is a complete stand alone view)

Regardless, refreshing the page in api.base.patient will still remove the patient id :/

Comment: What happens when you refresh the page in api.base.store, do you lose the storeID too?

Comment: The normal flow of the app is this:
1. entering site ("/") will redirect to /store/ (that app.base.store without a store id)
2. Once you select a store id your redirect to /store/storeID/patient/ with no patient selected.
3. As a result I never tried to enter /store/storeID route before - but it seems to automatically redirect to /store/storeID/patient/ (aka adding the /patient/)

It's kinda obvious we structured this badly (I've never used ui-router before and joined a half built app) but I would have expected it to accept a /store/storeID url without redirecting?

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a rogue

```
this.$state.go('app.base.patient', {storeID: value.id, patientID: null});
```

I originally added the explicit patientID: null as I thought it's needed - it's not and will cause the said problem during load.